# Foreach Loop Issue with Multidimensional Array

Tags: powershell

I have created a 2D array with 2 different first and last names but my foreach loop is not writing just the last names on the screen it is writing the first and last names.  And I am doing this in Windows PowerShell

PowerShell Script below

```
$arrays = ('John','Cans'),('Billy','Cans')
write-host $arrays
write-host $arrays[1][1] '  ' $array[0][1]
foreach ($arrays in $array) {Write-host $arrays}
```

Comment: It's doing exactly what you told it to do.

Comment: yes but how would it look like if it was written with 3 different first and last names, and how can I make the foreach loop just write the last names on the screen and not the first and last name

Comment: `foreach ($arrays in $array)` --> `foreach ($array in $arrays)`

Comment: @iRon - Definitely - not sure how I missed that error...

Comment: @omegaprime12 - as iRon pointed out, you had your $Vars reversed in your `foreach` loop. that is one reason for the best practice recommendation to always use _vividly different names_. a better choice in your example would be `foreach ( $A_Item in $Arrays) {}`.

Answer (score 4):

Tell the loop to write the bit you want. It;'s also less confusing if you use more distinct descriptive variables:

```
$arrays = ('John','Cans'),('Billy','Cans')

foreach ($item in $arrays) {Write-host $item[1]}
```

Answer (score 3):

Powershell was never intended to use the multidimensional array concept found in BASIC like languages.  Instead, powershell was designed to be used with OOP structs.  When you find yourself wanting to use a multidimensional array, this is a huge indicator you should be using either a hashtable or a custom object.  In essence, you're fighting the system.

```
[array]$People = @(
    [hashtable]@{FirstName = 'John'
      LastName  = 'Cans'
    },
    [hashtable]@{FirstName = 'Billy'
      LastName  = 'Cans'
    }
)

Foreach($Person in $people){
    $Person.LastName
}
```

In the above example we're creating an array of hashtables.  I've verbosely written in the datatype to make it easier for you to follow.  Typically I'd use an `arraylist` since you'll want to do adds and deletes I assume, but that's a lil bit more of an advanced concept and I don't want to throw too much at you at one time.

Now, the way I'd code what you're trying to do is with proper objects:

```
using namespace system.collections
class Person {
    [String]$FirstName
    [String]$Lastname

    Person($FirstName,$LastName){
        $this.FirstName = $FirstName
        $this.Lastname  = $LastName

        $this
    }
}

[arraylist]$People = @()

$People += [Person]::new('John','Cans')
$People += [Person]::new('Billy','Cans')

Foreach($Person in $People){
    $Person.Lastname
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Some clarification:

1. PowerShell, like most C-family languages, does not have true multidimensional arrays (*without directly invoking the constructor of a rather obscure aspect of the language*); they're really arrays of arrays [of arrays of ...]. That's why you have two separate subscripting operations (`$array[0][0]`, etc.).
2. When you reference an array without a subscript, PowerShell assumes that you want to use the *entire* array.
3. The `foreach ($a in $b)` construct treats `$b` as an array, and iterates through it. If `$b` is an array of arrays, then each instantiation of `$a` is itself an array, and will be treated as such.

So, what's happening in your code is that you're looking at an array of arrays, and walking through it so that each step is an array of lesser 'rank'. It's still an array, though, and needs to be treated as such.

If we express the array in PowerShell notation, after your first line, you have `$arrays` containing the value `@(@('John','Cans'),@('Billy','Cans'))`. When you go into the `foreach (...)`, you assign one of the inner `@(...)` entities to `$array` each time.  ***This is still an array, and is treated as such.*** When you execute the `Write-Host`, you are trying to write the *entire* array, not just part of it. If you only want to write one (string) entity from within the array, you need to select which one with a subscript operator. So, your `Write-Host` in the `foreach (...)` wants to be `Write-Host $array[0]` for the first name, or `Write-Host $array[1]` for the last name.

Comment: PowerShell/.NET most certainly has multidimensional arrays: `$2DArray = [int[,]]::new(2,2); $2DArray[0,0] = 123` - they can be a bit of a pain to work with, but they're certainly there :)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen - OK, that's new to me; that's the first time I've seen that construct. I would never have thought to dive into .NET directly for something like this.

Comment: It's not even "diving into .NET" - `[0,0]` <- multi-dimensional index accessor syntax is native to PowerShell. But yeah, it is a bit of an obscure feature ^_^

Comment: That's nice, didn't know this either! This is probably a lot faster than the `$array[0][0]` we're all used to.

Comment: huh, that's pretty neat.

Answer (score 0):

As Scepticalist suggested just a minor modification

```
    $arrays = ('John','Can'),('Billy','Cans')

    foreach ($item in $arrays) {Write-host $item[0], $item[1]}
```